# How to segue into a new view controller from button in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue

How can I segue into a new view controller from a button that is in a table view cell? I need to send some data with it so I'm not sure if I can do that from my tableViewCell class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var profilePressed: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

@IBAction func profileNamePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    profilePressed?(self)
}
```

in your table view cell class, and this:

```
cell.profilePressed = { (cell) in
    let profileVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileVC") as! ProfileVC
    profileVC.initData(withPostedBy: message.postedBy)
    self.presentDetail(profileVC)
}
```

in your cell for row at index path function

Answer (score 0):

Structure the custom cell like

```
class MyCell:UITableViewCell { 

  weak var delegate:VCName? 

  @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {
     delegate?.performSegue(withIdentifier:"segue",sender:someValue)
  }

}
```

And inside the vc's `cellForRowAt`

```
let cell = ///
cell.delegate = self
```